# How to iterate pipeline with tags from git in Jenkins?

Tags: github, jenkins

**Updated**

I want to build and run many versions of my source code on Git which has many tags. The names of the tags have a rule. I want to run every versions of my source code if the tag of the version are fit to a specific policy. For example, I will merely run sources with tag staring with 'runnable-'.
Once I bring tag lists that satisfies with above, I want Jenkins to iterate a tag among tags list and trigger each one to run another pipeline which would clone source code into its working directory and build and deploy its binary to a remote server and send information for letting the remote server whether or not it is updated.

1) How can I get every tags from a repository of git?

2) How can I filter unmatched tags from the list above?

I could get the answer of 1) and 2) through below command

```
git tag –list ‘runnable-*
```

3) How can I iterate the source version of those tags? My initial thought is I will declare a global parameter to point out a tag name and trigger another pipeline for each one. But once I do like this, Is it possible to check each pipeline's result after all processes are done?

Answer (score 0):

As I mention here, a git tag -l can accept a pattern

```
git tag -l <pattern>
```

Then for each tag, you can `git checkout atag` in order to make your working tree reflect the content of that tag.
Each checkout will result in a **[detached HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head)**, but that won't matter since you don't develop (ie make new commits).